# ¿Problema con arrays?

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenos días amigos ya finalicé mi código el cual tiene como objetivo simular un torneo de baloncesto.
Primero se pedirá que se introduzca por teclado  8 nombres de equipos diferentes. Después de ingresarlos, se emparejaran (1° con 2°, 3° con 4°, 5° con 6° y 7° con 8°) por pantalla de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de cada : se debe introducir un numero por teclado que deber ser 1 o 2. Si escribimos 1 gana el equipo de la izquierda (local) y si escribimos 2 el de la derecha (visitante). Después de la primera ronda y de meter todos los ganadores se mostraran emparejados el ganador del partido 1 contra  el del 2 y el 3 contra el del 4 de esta manera (suposición ganan equipo1, equipo3, equipo6 y equipo7):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y nuevamente, despues de : ingresamos por teclado 1 o 2 dependiendo de quien gane (supongamos que equipo1 y equipo 6)
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Metemos por teclado quien gana y finalmente (supongamos que gana el 6):
Ganador: Equipo 6

// El código funciona normal guarda los resultados en un arreglo para cada ronda(Excepto en la ultima no lo veo necesario debido a que solo se guardara un resultado) pero el problema es que no se como asociar estos resultados (1 o 2) a el arreglo que tiene la información de los equipos(ingresada al inicio del código). Por eso a partir de la segunda ronda mostrara es los resultados ( 1 o 2 ) en la parte donde van los nombres de los equipos. En conclusión el código al final me mostrara un "El ganador es: 1" y no el nombre del equipo.

ADJUNTO EL CÓDIGO

```
      String baloncesto [] = new String[8]; 
      int resultados1 [] = new int [4];
      int resultados2 [] = new int [2];
        int y = 0;
        int g = 0;
        int ñ = 0;
        int t = 0;
        int gana = 0;
        while(y<8){
        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del equipo");
        Scanner sn = new Scanner (System.in);
        baloncesto[y]=sn.nextLine();
        y++;
        if(y==8){
          System.out.println("     Primera Ronda     ");
          for(int i  = 0; i<baloncesto.length-4; i++){ 
              System.out.println("1."+baloncesto[i*2]+" - "+"2."+baloncesto[(i*2)+1]+":");
        }
          while(g<4){
          Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);
          while(resultados1[g]!=1 && resultados1[g]!=2){
          resultados1[g]=sr.nextInt();
          }
          g++;
          if(g==4){
          System.out.println("     Primera Ronda     ");
              for(int s = 0; s<resultados1.length; s++){
              System.out.println("1."+baloncesto[s*2]+" -                                                  
                                          "+"2."+baloncesto[(s*2)+1]+":"+resultados1[s]);
        }
              System.out.println("     Segunda Ronda    ");
              for(int b = 0; b<2; b++){
                System.out.println("1."+resultados1[b*2]+" - "+"2."+resultados1[(b*2)+1]+":");

              }
              while(ñ<2){
               Scanner sv = new Scanner(System.in);
               while(resultados2[ñ]!=1 && resultados2[ñ]!=2){
               resultados2[ñ]=sv.nextInt();
               }
               ñ++;  
               if(ñ==2){
               for(int q= 0; q<2; q++){
                System.out.println("1."+resultados1[q*2]+" - 
                                                "+"2."+resultados1[(q*2)+1]+":"+resultados2[q]);

              }
               System.out.println("     Tercera Ronda    ");
               for(int c = 0; c<1; c++){
               System.out.println("1. "+resultados2[c*2]+" - "+"2."+resultados2[(c*2)+1]+":");
               }
               Scanner sp = new Scanner(System.in);
               while(gana !=1 && gana !=2){
               gana=sp.nextInt();

               }
               System.out.println("     Tercera Ronda    ");
               for(int e = 0; e<1; e++){
               System.out.println("1. "+resultados2[e*2]+" - "+"2."+resultados2[(e*2)+1]+":"+gana);
               }
               if(gana==1){
                   System.out.println("El ganador es : " + resultados2[t*2]);
               }
               else{
                  System.out.println("El ganador es : " + resultados2[t*2+1]); 
               }
               }

              }
          }



          }    

    }   

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que sería mejor si "reutilizaras" el array de equipos eliminando a los perdedores después de cada ronda así el array de equipos se reducirá a la mitad, es decir, al inicio empieza con 8, luego de poner los resultados queda con 4 equipos, luego con 2 y por último con el ganador, así puedes hacer torneos de 2, 4, 8, 16, etc. y por medio de un ciclo `while` lo vas manejando hasta que quede 1 equipo. Esto que te comento yo lo haría así:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int cantidadEquipos = 8;
    int ronda = 1;
    String[] equipos = new String[cantidadEquipos];
    String[] ganadores = null;

    Scanner sn = new Scanner (System.in);

    // Ingresa el nombre de los equipos
    for(int i = 0; i < equipos.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese nombre del equipo " + (i+1) + ": ");
        equipos[i] = sn.nextLine();
    }

    // Mientras haya más de 1 equipo todavía no hay campeón del torneo
    while(equipos.length > 1) {
        String rondaActual = "";
        switch (equipos.length) {
            case 2:
                rondaActual = "FINAL";
                break;
            case 4:
                rondaActual = "SEMIFINAL";
                break;
            default:
                rondaActual = "RONDA " + ronda;
                break;
        }

        // Imprime en pantalla los partidos de la ronda en ejecución
        System.out.println("--- " + rondaActual + " ---");
        for (int i = 0; i < equipos.length / 2; i++) {
            System.out.println(equipos[i * 2] + " vs " + equipos[i * 2 + 1]);
        }
        System.out.println("----------------");

        // Crea un array para guardar los ganadores de la ronda y pide al usuario que los ingrese partido por partido
        ganadores = new String[equipos.length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < equipos.length / 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Partido: 1." + equipos[i * 2] + " - 2." + equipos[i * 2 + 1]);
            System.out.print("Ingrese al ganador: ");
            int ganador = sn.nextInt();
            switch (ganador) {
                case 1:
                    ganadores[i] = equipos[i * 2];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ganadores[i] = equipos[i * 2 + 1];
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("El ganador de " + equipos[i * 2] + " vs " + equipos[i * 2 + 1] + " es " + ganadores[i] + "\n");
        }
        equipos = ganadores;
        ronda++;
    }

    // Imprime al campeón del torneo
    System.out.println("--- CAMPEON ---");
    System.out.println(equipos[0]);
    System.out.println("---------------");

    sn.close();
}
```

Comment: Buenas noches amigo, excelente  respuesta es mas corta ademas que soluciona mi inconveniente y como dice usted es posible implementar este código para otros torneos (16,24,32). Voy a tratar de adecuar su código al que yo tenia planteado a ver si consigo la misma respuesta. Gracias